# How to implement multi tenant architecture in SSAS

Tags: ssas, olap, olap-cube

We have a **multi tenant** data warehouse (SQL Server 2012 Standard) and I want find out how we should **implement that in SQL Server Analysis Services**.

Currently the source data in the data warehouse is in a separate schema for each client. Like this: SELECT * FROM Datawarehouse.Client1.FactSales. There is a separate SSAS database for each client and 3 cubes in each SSAS database.

When we have a new client, we (1) script an existing SSAS database, (2) find and replace the client name, and then (3) run the script. That builds a new SSAS database for the new client.

We currently have 3 clients using our SSAS cubes and plan to have about 8 cubes with about 20 to 30 clients using them.

Although this works, **is this the best way to implement multi tenant architecture in SSAS?** I want to confirm this before we starting add more clients and cubes. And our solution need to be **secure**: client1 cannot see Client2's data

Comment: Look into SSAS roles. You can use those to secure your data in the SSAS database. You can either directly map users to a specific dimension attribute (client name or ID), or you can create dynamic security tables that map users to clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, mmarie: SSAS roles is what I need to use